# How to add or mimic the ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO a column in Snowflake, we have this in SQL Server

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have to create a table in Snowflake similar to what i have in SQL server question is about the below statements, where we have that ADD Classfication. Any idea other than masking those columns and statements to implement similar features.

CREATE TABLE test_staging(
'Event Date' varchar(250) NULL,
'Employee ID' varchar(250) NULL,
Amount varchar(250) NULL,
Hours varchar(250) NULL,
'Currency Code' varchar(250) NULL,
'Pay Type' varchar(250) NULL,
'Check Date' varchar(250) NULL,
FileName nvarchar(260) NULL
) ON PRIMARY

ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO test_staging.Amount WITH (label = 'Confidential', label_id = '8e9913ef-0360-4da5-b591-9c89cba52b8a', information_type = 'Financial', information_type_id = 'c44193e1-0e58-4b2a-9001-f7d6e7bc1373', rank = Medium);

ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO test_staging.'Currency Code' WITH (label = 'Confidential', label_id = '8e9913ef-0360-4da5-b591-9c89cba52b8a', information_type = 'Financial', information_type_id = 'c44193e1-0e58-4b2a-9001-f7d6e7bc1373', rank = Medium);

Comment: I don't know SQL server - what's the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

The Tagging functionality plays a similar role in Snowflake.

Please see this article: [Object Tagging Is Now Available in Public Preview](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/object-tagging-is-now-available-in-public-preview/)

Documentation: [Object Tagging](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/object-tagging.html)